# how to open a file in SL 4.0 without OpenFileDialog?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

is there an easy way to open a file in read mode from a local drive in Silverlight 4.0? I think there is OpenFileDialog, but I dont want to show any dialog to use but silently read some file on local drive

Answer (score 1):

The only way to do this is with the Silverlight app running Out-of-browser with elevated trust.  Even then the folders you can access are restricted  to the users `MyDocuments`, `MyMusic`, `MyPictures` and `MyVideos` as defined in teh `Environemnt.SpecialFolder` enum.

For security reason any other access must be explicitly granted by the user via the `OpenFileDialog`.

Answer (score 0):

While there is no way to do this (outside of going out-of-browser to restricted folders) in Silverlight 4, there are options to do this in Silverlight 5.